# A Macro using sizeof(arrays) is not giving the expected output

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int arr[] = {1, 2,3,4,5};
#define TOT (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]))

int main()
{
    int d = -1, x = 0;
    if(d<= TOT){
       x = arr[4];
       printf("%d", TOT);
    }
    printf("%d", TOT);
}
```

TOT has the value 5 but the if condition is failing..why is that?

Comment: You have [UB](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?UndefinedBehavior) in the `printf`s: you say you will pass an `int` but the type of `TOT` does not match.

Comment: @pmg Are there actually C compilers supporting %zd syntax? It seems not even GCC does this, I tried with -std=c99 -pedantic and it prints "zd".

Comment: @pmg I guess I have a far too old version of GCC...

Comment: My compiler (gcc 4.6.2) behaves correctly. So does ideone's (gcc 4.3.4) -- http://ideone.com/uw7Mg -- but this is not a compiler issue: it's a library issue. The culprit is `printf`'s implementation in libc (or wherever). Compiling with `gcc -std=c89 -pedantic` produces the same result (I get a warning with `-Wformat` for the C89 compilation only)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because there are "the usual arithmetic conversions" at work for the `if`.

The `sizeof` operator returns an unsigned type ... and `d` is converted to unsigned making it greater than the number of elements in `arr`.

Try

```
#define TOT (int)(sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]))
```

or

```
 if(d<= (int)TOT){
```

Comment: To be picky, the implicit promotion taking place here is "the usual arithmetic conversions" (aka balancing). The "integer promotions" typically refer to when a small integer type is implicitly converted to an `int`. Unless of course size_t is smaller than an int, but I don't think the C standard allows that.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `sizeof` returns an unsigned number, while `d` is signed. When `d` implicitly converted to a singed number, and then it is much much larger than `TOT`.

You should get a warning about comparison of signed-unsigned comparison from the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression for `TOT` is an *`unsigned`* value because the `sizeof()` operator always returns unsigned (positive) values.

When you compare the *`signed`* variable `d` with it, `d` gets automatically converted to a very large *`unsigned`* value, and hence becomes *larger* than `TOT`.

Answer (score 0):

return type of sizeof is unsigned integer ....that is why if is failing ...because "d" which is treated as signed by the compiler is greater than TOT